# Why does my TKinter GUI code work from interactive shell, but not when run from a file?

Tags: python, tkinter, interactive

I am trying to take some of my codes that have a command line interface and give them GUI's.  However, I am running into a problem. Can anyone help me understand why when I run my code from a file, nothing happens, but if I run it interactively, it works fine?  A simple example is below.  BTW, I am running Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10.  Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#--------------------------
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Test Window')
window.geometry('1000x800')
```

Comment: Can you explain how you "run my code from a file"? Is this a double click? A command prompt command? (if so what command)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't call the `mainloop` function. Tkinter automatically processes events when run interactively, but you need to explicitly start the event loop when not running interactively. Your code is running, but because you never tell it to start listening for events it exits at the end of the file just like any other python script.

You should add `window.mainloop()` as the last line in your file.

Comment: Yep.  Stpid mistake.  Thank you very much!